# DEFINE vs Variable in PHP

Tags: php

Can someone explain the difference between using

```
define('SOMETHING', true);
```

and

```
$SOMETHING = true;
```

And maybe the benefits between one or the other?

I use variables everywhere and even in a config type file that is included to everypage I still use variables as I don't see why to use the define method.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

DEFINE makes a constant, and constants are global and can be used anywhere. They also cannot be redefined, which variables can be.

I normally use DEFINE for Configs because no one can mess with it after the fact, and I can check it anywhere without global-ling, making for easier checks.

Comment: Can I pass the user's id from database into session? e.g. define($_SESSION['user_id'],row['id']) which the row['id'] is coming from database

Answer (score 14):

Once defined, a 'constant' cannot be changed at runtime, whereas an ordinary variable assignment can.

Constants are better for things like configuration directives which should not be changed during execution. Furthermore, code is easier to read (and maintain & handover) if values which are meant to be constant are *explicitly* made so.

Answer (score 9):

There is also a difference in scope.

In the example given by the orignal poster, `$SOMETHING` will not be accessible within a function whereas `define('SOMETHING', true)` will be.

Comment: that was a great and useful tip in config files with lots of functions inside it

Answer (score 7):

*define()* makes a read-only variable, compared to a standard variable that supports read and write operations.

Comment: just a note - i don't see how the term "read-only variables" applies to define() - as the manual states, it defines a *named constant*, which is something quite different.

Comment: -1: erroneous, and even if it were not it simply reiterates the above two posts.

Comment: A constant is not a variable by definition (no pun intended) ;-)

Comment: @hobodave ... yeah, except that it was postet 1 hour BEFORE the "above" two posts ... apart from that, i don't see, how this is erroneous ... in many languages constants are readonly variables ... apart from the fact, that a "constant" is semantically more clear, it is more less interchangable with "read-only variable" ...

Answer (score 0):

A constant is very useful when you want access data from inside  a function, check this

```
<?php
function data(){
  define("app","hey you can see me from outside the function",false);
  $tech = "xampp";
}
data();
echo $tech;
echo app;
?>
```

If you use a variable you are never going to get the inside value here is what i get

**Notice: Undefined variable: tech in D:\xampp\htdocs\data\index.php on line 8
hey you can see me from outside the function**