# PHP Should I use CONSTANTS or VARIABLES

Tags: php

I would like to know when should one use a constant and when should 1 use a variable in PHP
E.g.

```
define ("haha", "too bad");
$haha = "too bad";
```

Comment: You should use constants if you want to ensure that the value will not/cannot get changed anywhere after it's been defined. Variables everywhere else, I think.

Comment: I'd start by reading the fine manual. [Constants](http://php.net/manual/language.constants.php) / [Variables](http://php.net/manual/language.variables.php)

Comment: Use constants for constants and variables for variables.

Comment: @Phil This is acutally a language unspecific question. It's very unlikely that the PHP manual will provide that answer, plus I didn't find it there as well.

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch OP specifically says *"... in PHP"*. The first paragraph for *Constants* speaks pretty clearly about their intended use

Comment: @Phil what a long n arduous approach... just ask the question here and wait for the answer much easier...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First I'd like to propose not to follow those advices using constants for configuration. This will make your code hard to test (against a test environment) plus it's very unconventional to deploy code where you have to edit code for application configuration.

You will most of the time use variables. This brings the question to when should you use constants. Those points come to my mind:

- Use constants for [Magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29).
- Use constants to express semantic for a defined set of distinct values where the value itself doesn't matter. E.g. it doesn't really matter what values these constants will have: `STATE_NEW`, `STATE_OLD`, `STATE_DELETED`

Answer (score 2):

Use constants for values you define only once and you know that you'll never change them again in your script, usually some config information like

`define("MYSQLUSER", "root");
define("MYSQLHOST", "localhost");
...`

Use variables for all dynamic values in your script like

`$a = 1 * 2;
$b = $a % 4;`

Also, you might want to check back on the PHP manual or the resource you're learning PHP with because this is pretty basic and should be found easily via Google.

Comment: this is a good answer, why downvote it?

Comment: configuration goes into property files, which can easily edited for deployment. I wonder how you write your tests with all those constant configurations.

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch I think defining config values is a good example to show the use of constants on this basic level, I assume he's not thinking about file system structure too much at this point but I have to admit that you're right with this objection.

Comment: Not sure that directing a user to a manual (or Google) serves the purpose of this site.  Especially considering a Google search will in fact bring people directly to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

DEFINE makes a constant, and constants are global and can be used anywhere. They also cannot be redefined, which variables can be.

I normally use DEFINE for Configs because no one can mess with it after the fact, and I can check it anywhere without global-ling, making for easier checks.

See manual:
 [Constants](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.constants.php) | 
 [Variables](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.php)

Font: [DEFINE vs Variable in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225082/define-vs-variable-in-php)

As reminded by our friend @TecBrat in review, the PHP devs also use constants for [magic numbers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php). Quite often for bitmasked values.

Comment: The PHP devs also use constants for magic numbers. Quite often for bitmasked values.

Comment: @TecBrat I edited the post as well remembered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use constants on things I know will not change and are more 'important to the code'

For example, I use it when I define my working directory:

```
$base_url = '/subfolder/';
$doc_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$base_url;
define("DOC_ROOT", $doc_root);
```

Later, when I have to include files...

```
include(DOC_ROOT.'includes/header.php');
```

It is personal preference.

Comment: Why not just use `__DIR__`? It's far more portable

Answer (score 0):

The principal distinction between the two is that constants cannot be changed at runtime; in other words once set a constant cannot have a value assigned. These are great for things that would only change very rarely, if ever. If you know any Java: PHP constants are very similar to public static final variables there.

Variables on the other hand have no such restrictions.

If there's any change you'll need to change the value during the execution of your script you'll need to use variables.

Comment: public static final properties in Java are more akin to [class constants](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.constants.php) in PHP

Comment: @phil Fair enough. My php is a bit rusty.