# How to use declared variables in a PHP file in another PHP file?

Tags: php

I have a problem with some variables in PHP.
I need to get the value of the variable that is found, for example, in example.php and I need to get that value, but now in executable.php.

I already tried with:

```
Include, require_once and require
```

But it does not work for me, since in executable.php there is already an include (that I need) and to put the other include i get an error of 500 internal server error.

Also use $ GLOBALS ['varexample'] in example.php and global varexample in executable.php, but I mark the same error.

I hope someone can help

Comment: Would you mind posting more code? It could be a number of things. :-)

Comment: Without actual code we can't really help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DEFINE vs Variable in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225082/define-vs-variable-in-php)

Comment: use `require_once` everywhere you including `example.php`

Comment: @RushilPachchigar I don't think so... Constatns aren't the same as GLOBAL scope variables.

Answer (score 0):

Example: file1.php contains the variables you want to call on file2.php so you can use require (or require_once) to use these variables. (NOTE: If you declare a variable and you want to use it inside a function you must use global keyword first).

file1.php:

```
<?php
$var1 = "foo";
$var2 = "bar";
?>
```

file2.php

```
<?php
require 'file1.php';
echo $var1." ".$var2; // OUTPUT: foo bar
?>
```

file2.php (call variables inside a function):

```
<?php
require 'file1.php';

function myFunction() {
    global $var1, $var2;
    return $var1." ".$var2;
}
?>

echo myFunction() // OUTPUT: foo bar
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want variables accessible from all your php files, you could try using [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php).

```
//example.php
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["var1"] = $var1;
    $_SESSION["var2"] = $var2;
?>

//executable.php
<?php
    session_start();
    $var3 = $_SESSION["var1"];
    $var4 = $_SESSION["var2"];
?>
```