# WordPress to begin learning Databases

Tags: wordpress

I am inspecting WordPress' `wp-config.php` file. I used this guide to help go through things a bit "A guided tour of wp-config.php."

However, most of it was mostly just repeating the name of variables.

These define statements let us use `define('DB_PASSWORD', 'somePass');`.

What is this "method" actually doing?

Bonus question. I have a password in that method; however, it is encrypted. Is that what the database is looking for or does it want the plaintext password? If so, where is the algorithm to decrypt that password?

Comment: Everything about that function is explained in the documentation about that function here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php. it defines a constant DB_PASSWORD. A constant is like a variable that never changes during runtime. Wordpress uses the constant when it connects to the db. For your bonus question: WordPress expects  the raw unencrypted password for the database connection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DEFINE vs Variable in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225082/define-vs-variable-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Happy to help,

`define('DB_PASSWORD', 'somePass');` is the MYSQL password to your website database.

**Example:**

```
define('DB_NAME', 'name_of_your_database');
define('DB_USER', 'mysql_user_name');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mysql_password');
```

This tells Wordpress to look for Database: **name_of_your_database** with your MYSQL user credentials Username: **mysql_user_name** and Password: **mysql_password**

Comment: Can I ask an additional question? This is a php document that resides on the server. The browser opens and runs the script. Then the php asks for the MYSQL to communicate. Is MYSQL running? Or is php just rooting around in more script documents? Is the php document just pulling from another document or a program?

Comment: Think of it more as login information. This basically just tells Wordpress what database to use and how to log into it. I'm assuming you're working locally and using PhpMyAdmin locally? You can see the relationship if you log into PhpMyAdmin and find the database you're using.

Comment: "This basically just tells Wordpress what database to use and how to log into it"   What is it using and how does it log onto it? I mean is the browser accessing just more documents or communicating with a running program on the databaes? Just the linux O/S? MYSQL running program? Just raw document tables?