# php echo loop, unable to echo stored value in define

Tags: php, loops

The following code displays the news article date, title/header, and article.

```
<h2><?php echo(LATEST_NEWS_ARTICLE_DATE_10);?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<?php echo(LATEST_NEWS_ARTICLE_HEADER_10);?></h2>
<p><?php echo(LATEST_NEWS_ARTICLE_10);?>
```

....articles 9 through to 2.....

```
<h2><?php echo(LATEST_NEWS_ARTICLE_DATE_1);?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<?php echo(LATEST_NEWS_ARTICLE_HEADER_1);?></h2>
<p><?php echo(LATEST_NEWS_ARTICLE_1);?>
```

displays:-

article 10:-

31st March 2021  PHP Loop still issues

Whats going on with this loop still

....articles 9 to 2....

article 1:-
31st March 2020  PHP Loop

Whats going on with this loop

but rather than type the code out for each article (eventually 20 articles per page, multi pages), thought I would use a loop.

```
<?php
for ($x = 10; $x > 0; $x--) {
echo (LATEST_NEWS_ARTICLE_DATE_.$x)."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
echo (LATEST_NEWS_ARTICLE_HEADER_.$x)."<br>";
echo (LATEST_NEWS_ARTICLE_.$x)."<br><br>";
}
?>
```

This should display the latest article 10, to the oldest article 1, but instead it displays

LATEST_NEWS_ARTICLE_DATE_10    LATEST_NEWS_ARTICLE_HEADER_10
LATEST_NEWS_ARTICLE_10

.....articles 9 through to 2.....

LATEST_NEWS_ARTICLE_DATE_1    LATEST_NEWS_ARTICLE_HEADER_1
LATEST_NEWS_ARTICLE_1

I must be missing something as its so close. Any help including tutorials to try would be appreciated, I haven't been able to find something yet.

Comment: Where does `LATEST_NEWS_ARTICLE_DATE_` come from? Are you implementing new code for every new post???

Comment: `LATEST_NEWS_ARTICLE_DATE_.$x` - That will try and concatenate the value of the constant `LATEST_NEWS_ARTICLE_DATE_` and the value of the variable `$x`. Constants are not the correct tool for what you're trying to do. Define a multidimensional array with all the news and iterate through that instead.

Comment: @B001ᛦ I guess I am in that I would define the next article when written.

Comment: @ Magnus Eriksson thanks. looking at it the wrong way, I will look at the array option.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work the way you expect it to work - PHP will always evaluate your construct to the value of a constant named `LATEST_NEWS_ARTICLE_` plus the value of the variable `$x`.

You're on the right track using a loop to iterate over a data set, though, but to store the data, you should definitely use a variable, not a constant (cf. [DEFINE vs Variable in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225082/define-vs-variable-in-php)).

The most obvious choice would be an array, e.g.:

```
$latest_articles = [

    ['date' => '...', 'header' => '...', 'body' => '...'],
    ['date' => '...', 'header' => '...', 'body' => '...']
];
```

Later in your code, you could simply loop over it with `foreach`:

```
foreach ($latest_articles as $article) {

    echo($article['date']);
    echo($article['header']);
    ...    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I am looking at it the wrong way as looking to use what i have got rather than rearrange what i have. I will have a look at this and it makes some sense at least.